# using NSUserDefaults for TintColor change

Tags: ios, save, boolean, nsuserdefaults, tintcolor

I am having an UIBarButtonItem in my UINavigationBar. Having there a picture of the star (white one). If user clic on the star I have set that the tint color of star going to be yellow, as meaning of favorite one. And if user tap on the white star once, it changes the color and then user close the app. I would like to have still the star selected, if he does tap on it. It works but don`t save after run again. Any ideas?

```
static UIBarButtonItem *barb1;
@interface ViewControllerDetail (){
    BOOL kokos;
}

-(void)changestarr{
if (kokos) {
            [barb1 setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            kokos = NO;

        } else {
            [barb1 setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
            kokos = YES;
            prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [prefs setObject:[UIColor yellowColor] forKey:@"yess"];
            [prefs synchronize];
            NSString *message = @"You got it.";

            UIAlertView *toast = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [toast show];

            int duration = 1.7;

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [toast dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

            });
        }}
```

**Viewdidload**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        kokos = NO;
        barb1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                               target:self
                                                               action:@selector(changestarr)];

         barb2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"final.png"]
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                               target:self
                                                             action:@selector(showfinal)];
        [barb1 setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barb1, barb2, nil];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi first you should set your first off default values.

```
-(void)setDefaults
{
 NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"BarButtonColor" : @1 }; // where 1 is white

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary]; 

}
```

Now call -(void)setDefaults in your init method for your view controller.
Then change -(void)viewDidLoad to the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 // If you do not want to set defaults in init

 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"BarButtonColor"] == 0) {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey: @"BarButtonColor"];
     }



    kokos = NO; // Remove
    barb1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                           target:self
                                                           action:@selector(changestarr)];

     barb2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"final.png"]
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                           target:self
                                                         action:@selector(showfinal)];
    // changes
    NSInteger color = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"BarButtonColor"];

    if (color == 1) {
    [barb1 setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    } else if (colour == 2) {
    [barb1 setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    }

    // finished changes

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barb1, barb2, nil];

}
```

And then finally change -(void)changstarr to the following

```
-(void)changestarr{

NSInteger color = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"BarButtonColor"];

if (color == 2) {
        [barb1 setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"BarButtonColor"]];

    } else if (color == 1) {
        [barb1 setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:2 forKey:@"BarButtonColor"]];
        NSString *message = @"You got it.";

        UIAlertView *toast = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [toast show];

        int duration = 1.7;

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [toast dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

        });
    }}
```

You might want to put in error checks for if the app is ever terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: Nice, Thanks. Don`t you know how to set the action just in one of Detail View, not in all of them?

Comment: Do you mean not registering user defaults? if you call for an integer that is not set it will return 0 so you could set it that way in viewDidLoad